# Available projections for gvisGeoChart

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

Does anyone know of complete list of available projections available in the googleVis package?

At the moment I have only got the options `kavrayskiy-vii` and `lambert` to work. I can not find any documentation with reference to other possible projections in the package documentation or in the [Google Chart Tools API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart).

```
library(googleVis)
G1b <- gvisGeoChart(Exports, locationvar='Country', colorvar='Profit',
               options=list(projection="kavrayskiy-vii"))

plot(G1b)
```

Comment: IIRC (as of 2013) the supported projections are: `mercator`, `albers`, `lambert` and `kavrayskiy-vii`.